# Static Go Binaries w/ Docker - Entrypoint Not Found

Tags: go, makefile, docker, dockerfile

I used [Static Go Binaries with Docker on OSX](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/07/osx-static-golang-binaries-with-docker/?hn) by Nicola Paolucci to try to use static Go binary w/ Docker. I believe I followed every step correctly, but when I run the final image, I get the following error response from Docker.

*NOTE* The name of my service and executable are `netverify`

```
docker: Error response from daemon: Container command '/netverify' not found or does not exist..
```

My `Dockerfile.static` looks like the following...

```
#Create a minimal container to run a Golang static binary

FROM tianon/true
ADD netverify /
EXPOSE 8282
CMD ["/netverify"]
```

My `Dockerfile.build` looks like the following...

```
FROM golang

ADD Makefile /
WORKDIR /
RUN make setup

ADD . /go/src/github.com/eirwin/netverify

RUN make buildgo
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

My `Makefile` is the following...

```
GOCMD = go
GOBUILD = $(GOCMD) build
GOGET = $(GOCMD) get -v
GOCLEAN = $(GOCMD) clean
GOINSTALL = $(GOCMD) install
GOTEST = $(GOCMD) test

.PHONY: all

all: build

setup:
    $(GOGET) github.com/gorilla/mux

buildgo:
    GOOS=linux $(GOBUILD) -o netverify ./go/src/github.com/eirwin/netverify

builddocker:
    docker build -t eirwin/netverify -f ./Dockerfile.build .
    docker run -t eirwin/netverify /bin/true
    docker cp `docker ps -q -n=1`:/netverify .
    chmod 755 ./netverify
    docker build --rm=true --tag=eirwin/netverify -f Dockerfile.static .

run:    builddocker
    docker run -p 8282:8282 eirwin/netverify
```

For the purpose of this post, lets assume I have the following as my golang application.

```
func main() {

    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.HandleFunc("/ping", api.PingHandler).Methods("GET")
    http.ListenAndServe(":8282", router)
}
```

When I run `Make run` everything seems to work except for when the image is ran.

I can see that the image builds correctly at ~8.5MB

```
eirwin/netverify  latest  eae16e146b91 3 seconds ago       8.63 MB
```

But when If `docker run -p 8282:8282 eirwin/netverify` is ran I get the following error...

```
docker: Error response from daemon: Container command '/netverify' not found or does not exist..
```

Comment: What "following article"? I don't see anything in here about building a static binary, or what having a static binary would have to do with the docker error.

Comment: @JimB I updated the post. My apologies.

Comment: You're not building a static binary per the directions. I'm not sure if that's the only problem, but you need to start there. Also the `tianon/true` image doesn't look particularly useful. You can start with `scratch` yourself, or use something a little more complete like `alpine`

Answer (score 2):

The go static build in your makefile is missing some options.

```
buildgo:
    CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -ldflags "-s" -a -installsuffix cgo -o netverify ./go/src/github.com/eirwin/netverify
```

The build process can capture the container ID to avoid timing issues. 
Separate the tags for build and binary images.

```
builddocker:
    docker build -t eirwin/netverify-build -f ./Dockerfile.build .
    CID=$$(docker create eirwin/netverify-build); \
    docker cp $$CID:/netverify .; \
    docker rm $$CID
    chmod 755 ./netverify
    docker build --rm=true --tag=eirwin/netverify -f Dockerfile.static .
```

Your binary `Dockerfile.static` can start with the `scratch` blank image.

```
FROM scratch
```