# Choosing Golang docker base image

Tags: docker, go, alpine-linux

Size of the images `golang` and `alpine` vary by around `300Mb`.

What are the advantages of using `golang` image instead of plain `alpine`?

Comment: If you create a [static go binary](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/07/osx-static-golang-binaries-with-docker/?hn), you can use [`scratch`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38711044/1318694)

Comment: There is also `golang:alpine`.

Comment: @Зелёный Yes there is `golang:alpine` but it is ~200Mb more than base `alpine`. just want to know what is the advantage of golang image

Comment: The main advantage is obviously `go` lang tools(and many other tools such as `git` or `bash`), those tools don't available in plain alpine docker images. [Here is a good thread about a __small__ docker images](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=10782897). I think your question is probably off-topic here IMO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: It would be fairer to compare the differences between `golang:alpine` and `alpine`.

At the time of writing, the `golang` image is built off of Debian, a different distribution than Alpine. [I'll quote the documentation from Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/golang/):

> `golang:<version>`
>
> This is the defacto image. If you are unsure about
>   what your needs are, you probably want to use this one. It is designed
>   to be used both as a throw away container (mount your source code and
>   start the container to start your app), as well as the base to build
>   other images off of.

and

> `golang:alpine`
>
> This image is based on the popular Alpine Linux project,
>   available in the alpine official image. Alpine Linux is much smaller
>   than most distribution base images (~5MB), and thus leads to much
>   slimmer images in general.
>
> This variant is highly recommended when final image size being as
>   small as possible is desired. The main caveat to note is that it does
>   use musl libc instead of glibc and friends, so certain software might
>   run into issues depending on the depth of their libc requirements.
>   However, most software doesn't have an issue with this, so this
>   variant is usually a very safe choice. See this Hacker News comment
>   thread for more discussion of the issues that might arise and some
>   pro/con comparisons of using Alpine-based images.

In summary, images built off of Alpine will tend to be smaller than the Debian ones. But, they won't contain various system tools that you may find useful for development and debugging. A common compromise is to build your binaries with the `golang` flavor and deploy to production with either `golang:alpine`, `alpine`, or as mentioned in a comment above, `scratch`.

Comment: So in summary it is better to use just `alpine` image in production and `golang;alpine` for development and building the image ?

Comment: Yes, for some use cases. That would be a good rule of thumb if you don't mind using a minimal distro (Alpine will generally need additional configuration to make your app function properly).

Comment: Original comment with the link mentioned: https://github.com/docker-library/golang/issues/209

Answer (score 7):

Why not [scratch](https://hub.docker.com/_/scratch/)?

You can build a static go binary file and copy it into the docker image.

The size of the docker image will be equal to the size of the binary file.

Suppose that your go binary file is called **main_go**, this is the *Dockerfile* that you need:

```
FROM centurylink/ca-certs
ADD main_go /
CMD ["/main_go"]
```

Please remember that *scratch* and *centurylink* are blank images therefore you must statically compile your app with all libraries built in.

Example:

```
CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o main_go .
```

[Here](https://blog.codeship.com/building-minimal-docker-containers-for-go-applications/) you can find some extra info about docker, go and scratch and [here](https://www.goinggo.net/2013/10/cross-compile-your-go-programs.html) you can find some info about the GOOS value.

Update: Multi-stage builds using alpine to build the image.

```
ARG GO_VERSION=1.15.6
 
# STAGE 1: building the executable
FROM golang:${GO_VERSION}-alpine AS build
RUN apk add --no-cache git
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates
 
# add a user here because addgroup and adduser are not available in scratch
RUN addgroup -S myapp \
    && adduser -S -u 10000 -g myapp myapp
 
WORKDIR /src
COPY ./go.mod ./go.sum ./
RUN go mod download
 
COPY ./ ./
 
# Run tests
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 go test -timeout 30s -v github.com/gbaeke/go-template/pkg/api
 
# Build the executable
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 go build \
    -installsuffix 'static' \
    -o /app ./cmd/app
 
# STAGE 2: build the container to run
FROM scratch AS final
LABEL maintainer="gbaeke"
COPY --from=build /app /app
 
# copy ca certs
COPY --from=build /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /etc/ssl/certs/
 
# copy users from builder (use from=0 for illustration purposes)
COPY --from=0 /etc/passwd /etc/passwd
 
USER myapp
 
ENTRYPOINT ["/app"]
```

More info can be found [here](https://blog.baeke.info/2021/03/28/distroless-or-scratch-for-go-apps/).

Comment: Good call on `scratch` and `centurylink/ca-certs`. But if you `import "C"` or use a library that does, like a wrapper over a C library, you can't really use `scratch` though?

Comment: The centurylink repo isn't maintained anymore, so I'd suggest editing the answer and removing references to it.