# How base images (that are used to create user-defined images) for docker are created?

Tags: docker

Assume that we have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:latest
...
ENTRYPOINT ["./main"]
```

How the `alpine:latest` was created?

The explanations I've found are about using `scratch` to make docker images small, but they anyway use some other images to perform initial actions, for example:

```
FROM alpine:latest as build
# Do some stuff
# Get compiled binary ./main
FROM scratch
COPY ./main .
# Copy whatever we need to make our binary work
ENTRYPOINT ["./main"]
```

But how did they create `alpine:latest` and `scratch`?

Comment: `scratch` is not created, `scratch` is a special, empty image. All base images eventually point back to `scratch`.

Comment: @Turing85, thanks for reply. I'm aware that scratch is a special image, but it obviously was created. Nevertheless, how is alpine image created using scratch then?

Comment: No, `scratch` was not created, it is a keyword (see [here (`github.com`)](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/10737#issuecomment-74084238). A `scratch` image is an empty image, with no additional files, libraries, programs,... As to how an image is created `FROM scratch`: normally, a base layout is copied into the `scratch` container. This is similar how gentoo was installed in the old days: start a live system, copy a tarball, unpack the tarball and `chroot` into the environment.

Comment: @Turing85, OK, i see. So when an image for, say, `ubuntu` is created, developers just add layers above `scratch`? And, when I said that `scratch` was created, I meant it in the most general sense. Like, the docker itself was created, right?

Comment: "*So when an image for, say, `ubuntu` is created, developers just add layers above scratch?*" - Yes. --- As to `scratch`... there was a `scratch`-image a long time ago, but the semantics have been changed; `scratch` is a reserved keyword, and thus treated separtely (representing an empty contianer). Please see the link I added to my previous comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Docker Hub `alpine` image page](https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine) has links to Dockerfiles.  That gives you, for example, [this Dockerfile for Alpine 3.18](https://github.com/alpinelinux/docker-alpine/blob/66fa0fe063bbb4f03220088a4f4d8bb34db1b803/x86_64/Dockerfile) (quoted in its entirety):

```bash
FROM scratch
ADD alpine-minirootfs-3.18.2-x86_64.tar.gz /
CMD ["/bin/sh"]
```

So this image does in fact start from `scratch`, but the two important details are that it has a full Alpine root filesystem in a tar file, and that the Dockerfile `ADD` directive can uncompress and expand the archive.  The `CMD` is just a default to have something.

You can in fact build your own images `FROM scratch`, but it takes some care.  Most Linux binaries are *dynamically linked*, meaning they require at least two parts, a *dynamic loader* (`/lib/ld-linux.so.2` for example) and *shared libraries* (like `/lib/lib.so.6`).  Managing these by hand can be a little tricky.

If you can build a *static binary*, this will have all of the shared-library dependencies embedded into the binary itself, and you can use it in a `FROM scratch` image.  I feel like I most often see this for Go applications, though you can use it for any native-compiled language (also C, C++, Rust); [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47028597/choosing-golang-docker-base-image/47039404#47039404) has a complete example.

If you can't build a static binary, or you do need some language runtime (either you're using an interpreted language like Python or Javascript, or a bytecode language like Java or Elixir) then you'll probably find it far easier to use an `alpine`, `debian`, or `ubuntu` base than to try to build your image `FROM scratch` if you're not already familiar with Linux shared libraries.

If you wanted to learn or experiment, you might start off with a [`busybox`](https://hub.docker.com/_/busybox) image.  [BusyBox](https://busybox.net) is a statically-compiled tool (so no shared-library dependencies) that includes a large number of core Unix tools; the corresponding Docker image does not contain the C shared-library infrastructure.  This means that even if you do break the system C library, (a) it's in a container and won't affect your host, and (b) you have statically-linked `sh`, `ls, *etc.* and can still try to debug.